# Confused C pointer behavior

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, arguments

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printa(char *a[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {       
        printf("%s\n", *a);
        a++;
    }   
}

int main(void)
{
    char *a[] = {"The first", "The second", "The third"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", *a); 
        a++; // error: cannot increment value of type 'char *[3]'
    }

    printa(a); //OK 

    return 0;
}
```

Thus, my question is why the code `a++` in main function causing compile error (error: cannot increment value of type 'char *[3]'). But if I pass array of pointer a to function `printa` and call `a++` on that pointer, it works perfectly.

Thanks,

Comment: A is an array , each element of which is a pointer to a char.... so a++ will fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix `++` can't have operand of array type. The type of `a` in `main` function is `char *[3]`, i.e. *an **array** of pointers to `char`* while in function `printa` it is of type `char **`.

As a function parameter

```
char *a[]
```

is equivalent to

```
char **a
```

Comment: You mean that an array pass to function as a pointer. Thus, `char a[]` is equivalent to `char *a` and `char *a[]` is equivalent to `char **a`.

Comment: @Linh  Yes it is when passed in function.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. When an array is passed to a function then a pointer to its first element is passed to that function.

Comment: if you speak about function arg then yes, but inside the function *a[] is not the same as a**, no. First is Array and second is pointer

Comment: Why we cannot `++` on array type? Is it due to `a` is the base of array, thus we can change it?

Comment: @Linh; Read [this](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html).

Comment: @haccks: Thanks. I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply because array names are **non-modifiable l-value**. Which cannot be used as left operand in any expression. Therefore, you cannot keep it on the left side of a `=` expression, or increment it using an increment operator

Answer (score 1):

When you called printa function, the argument is now another variable of type char **. That variable you can increment.

But inside main, you can not modify **a** as its the base location of array. Else you get *I-Value* error.